# Binormal Vector Question

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

So suppose we have a space curve: $r=\langle \cos t, \sin t,3t\rangle$. The task is to find $N(0)$ and $B(0)$ where $N(t)$ is the normal tangent vector and $B(t)$ is the binormal tangent vector.

Formulas:
$T(t)=\frac{r'(t)}{||r'(t)||}$, $N(t)=\frac{T'(t)}{||T'(t)||}$, $B(t)=T(t) \times N(t)$

$r(t)=<cost,sint,3t>$

$r'(t)=<-sint,cost,3>$

$||r'(t)||=\sqrt{(-sint)^2+(cost)^2+(3)^2}=\sqrt{1+9}=\sqrt{10}$

$T(t)=\frac{<-sint,cost,3>}{\sqrt{10}} = <\frac{-sint}{\sqrt{10}},\frac{cost}{\sqrt{10}},\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}>$

$T(0)=<0,1,\frac{3}{\sqrt10}>$

$T'(t) = <\frac{-cost}{\sqrt{10}},\frac{-sint}{\sqrt{10}},0>$

$||T'(t)||=\sqrt{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}})^2[(-cost)^2+(-sint)^2]}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{10}(1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$

So,

$N(0)= <\frac{-cost\sqrt10}{\sqrt10},\frac{-sint\sqrt10}{\sqrt10},0>=<-1,0,0>$

$B(0)=T(0) \times N(0) = <0,1,\frac{3}{\sqrt10}> \times <-1,0,0> = <0,0,0>$

I get that $B(0)$ is a vector of zeroes which doesn't seem right. Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: last product is cross product, not dot (scalar), so $B(0)=(0;\frac{-\sqrt3}{10};-1)$

Comment: Point of terminology: “normal tangent” is an oxymoron.